# How to backup mails of my outlook [2010 beta]?

Tags: backup, microsoft-outlook

I configured my mail in outlook 2010 beta..

I want to backup all my mails to my system which uses windows 7...

- How to backup mails of my outlook [2010 beta]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a PST as a mail store, you would simply need to make a copy of the PST when outlook is closed.  The default path is C:\Users\Username\Document\Outlook Files\Outlook.pst.  Several different methods are available to make scheduled copies, but Microsoft's SyncToy is nice and easy.  Simply set up synchronization to run during a period when your Outlook is closed, and have it move the PST to your backup location.